# How to divide columns by a constant in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, dataframe, awk

I have sort of a table looking like this:

```
ERR843978.746 15 54 71
ERR843978.1705 7 45 51
ERR843978.5030 3 46 58
ERR843978.8855 15 48 52
ERR843978.4162 16 48 64
ERR843978.421 14 51 54
ERR843978.4599 12 60 46
ERR843978.5941 18 67 55
ERR843978.3780 15 56 70
```

and I would like to divide all columns expect the first one by the same number, e.g. to get this kind of output if I divide by 3 for example:

```
ERR843978.746 3 18 23.666
ERR843978.1705 2.333 15 17
ERR843978.5030 1 15.333 19.333
ERR843978.8855 5 19.333 17.333
...
```

That doesn't sound too hard but I couldn't come up with a way to do this in bash (I guess you could easily do that with Python too).

I would need a solution that's not too slow as my table is quite big in reality.

Comment: You cannot do this with just bash: bash cannot do floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)$i/=3}1' file
ERR843978.746 5 18 23.6667
ERR843978.1705 2.33333 15 17
ERR843978.5030 1 15.3333 19.3333
ERR843978.8855 5 16 17.3333
ERR843978.4162 5.33333 16 21.3333
ERR843978.421 4.66667 17 18
ERR843978.4599 4 20 15.3333
```

Pipe it to `column` for nices output:

```
$ awk ... | column -t
ERR843978.746   5        18       23.6667
ERR843978.1705  2.33333  15       17
ERR843978.5030  1        15.3333  19.3333
```

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i/3}} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: @JamesBrown, :) since command is a bit very bit different($i=$i/3) so keeping it. It was 6 sec slow though :) cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ane '$_ /= 3 for @F[1..$#F]; print "@F\n"' -- file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace and populates the @F array
- `$_ /= 3` is a shorthand for `$_ = $_ / 3`

Comment: works too but is (a bit) slower than the awk solution. thanks !